# How to apply differences on part of a list and keep the rest?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list,

```
l1 = {{a, b, 3, c}, {e, f, 5, k}, {n, k, 12, m}, {s, t, 1, y}}
```

and want to apply differences on the third parts and keep the parts right of the numerals collected.

My result should be

```
l2 = {{2, c, k}, {7, k, m}, {-11, m, y}}
```

I tried Map and MapAt, but I could not get anywhere. I could work around split things up and connect again. But is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this?:

```
l1 = {{a, b, 3, c}, {e, f, 5, k}, {n, k, 12, m}, {s, t, 1, y}};

l2 = Differences[l1[[All, 3 ;;]]] /. b_ - a_ :> Sequence[a, b]
(*  {{2, c, k}, {7, k, m}, {-11, m, y}}  *)
```

It assumes the letter symbols are simple and not complicated expressions.

This is more complicated, but more robust:

```
Flatten /@ 
 Transpose@
  MapAt[Differences, 
   Partition[Transpose@l1[[All, 3 ;;]], {1, 2}, {1, 1}], {1, All, 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to digest your answer.

Comment: How would you do it if 

l1= {{z,a, b, 3, c}, {w,e, f, 5, k}, {q,n, k, 12, m}, {p,s, t, 1, y}};

Comment: @user57467 I would change the third column to the fourth: `l1[[All, 4 ;;]]`.  You can programmatically get the column with `col = Position[First@l1, _?NumericQ][[1, 1]]` or `col = Position[First@l1, _Integer][[1, 1]]`; then use `l1[[All, col ;;]]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html) as follows:

```
BlockMap[{#[[3]].{-1, 1}, ## & @@ Flatten@#[[4 ;;]]} &@* Transpose, l1, 2, 1]
```

> {{2, c, k}, {7, k, m}, {-11, m, y}}

or

```
BlockMap[{#[[1]].{-1, 1}, ## & @@ Flatten@ #[[2 ;;]]} &@*Transpose, l1[[All, 3 ;;]], 2, 1]
```

> {{2, c, k}, {7, k, m}, {-11, m, y}}

Comment: I am impressed!

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to kglr's first solution but picks the relevant quantities a bit more explicitly:

```
l2 = BlockMap[{#[[2, 3]] - #[[1, 3]], #[[1, 4]], #[[2, 4]]} &, l1, 2, 1]
```

> {{2, c, k}, {7, k, m}, {-11, m, y}}

With a parameter to change the symbolic column quickly:

```
l2 = With[{col = 3},
  BlockMap[{#[[2,col]] - #[[1,col]], #[[1,col+1]], #[[2,col+1]]} &, l1, 2, 1]]
```

> {{2, c, k}, {7, k, m}, {-11, m, y}}

Comment: Wow! Good! I enjoy the clarity!

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `MapThread` on an offset `Partition`.

```
MapThread[Sequence @@ #@#2 &, {{Differences, Identity}, Transpose@#}] & /@ 
 Partition[l1[[All, 3 ;;]], 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{2, c, k}, {7, k, m}, {-11, m, y}}
> ```

`Differences` is applied to the integers while `Identity` preserves the form of the symbols.

Hope this helps.